# how to iterate over list of dataframes?

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, for-loop

Basically, I have 5 pd.dataframes, named= `df0, df1, df2, df3, df4`. What I would like to do is use a for loop to add data to these 5 dataframes. Something the likes of:

> ```
> for i, dataset in enumerate([df0,df1,df2,df3,df4]):
>     dataset = pd.concat([dataset, NEW_DATA])
> ```

However, when you do it like this (or when you use a solely list instead of enumerate), 'dataset' returns the dataset, rather than the name (i.e. df0). How can I solve this. For example, the output for the second iteration should be:

> ```
> for i, dataset in enumerate([df0,df1,df2,df3,df4]):
>     df1 = pd.concat([df1, NEW_DATA])
> ```

edit: I have also tried dictionaries, such as {'df0':df0... etc}, however, it again prints the dataset rather than the dataset 'variable name'.

Comment: How about `pd.concat([df0,df1,df2,df3,df4])`?

Comment: That doesn't work. These datasets should contain different values, due to the data imputation algorithm. The algorithm outputs 5 different versions of the 'guessed' missing data, which I want to append to separate datasets (in this case df0....df4).

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Rewriting the solution to provide some proper practice.

So the problem is you have a bunch of values that need to be updated through *reassignment*. There's a stylistic thing going on where if you have df1, df2, ..., maybe you'd much rather have them in a list.

Using a list in any case is also how I'd address the issue.

```
dfs = [df0, df1, df2, ...]
dfs = [pd.concat([df, NEW_DATA]) for df in dfs]
[df0, df1, df2, ...] = dfs
```

See how, if you'd just use `dfs` in general and refer to `dfs[0]` instead of `df0`, this solution could almost come for free?

Comment: Basically what I am trying to do is run a data imputation algorithm that outputs N-dataframes (in my case 5). I run the algorithm Y-times (ones for each location with missing values) and I want to append each of 5 dataframes to the dataframes I created: df0,df1,df2,df3,df4.

Comment: not clear why you need the name of the dataframes then?

Comment: OK I may know what you mean: You want to assign back to the dataframe in question, but the way you put it, it'll just overwrite the local variable with a new value but not change the original one.

By writing back into `d[name]`, that might fix it

Answer (score 0):

You can re-assign the new `df` into your list:

```py
# setup example
df0 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 10, (3, 2)))
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 10, (3, 2)))
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 10, (3, 2)))

# then
lst = [df0, df1, df2]
for i, df in enumerate(lst):
    newdata = pd.DataFrame([[0,0], [0,0]])  # (say)
    lst[i] = df.append(newdata)
df0, df1, df2 = lst
```

```py
>>> df0
   0  1
0  8  7
1  9  1
2  5  6
0  0  0
1  0  0
```

But, BTW, it might be better to store your DataFrames collection in a `dict` instead of a list, if you want to refer to them by name instead of by index.